# How to deploy static website from public repo via Github Actions to private web server

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, github, secret-management

I like to start an open-source project via Github where topics (markdown pages) can be created from the community. Via PR the changes get merged to the main repo and then it triggers a Github Action workflow. Inside this workflow, the markdown input gets processed to static HTML pages which should later get deployed to an Nginx web server.

The current (prototyped) deployment is done via [SCP for GitHub Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scp-files) and [SSH for GitHub Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands). For both actions, I have to provide the user and password inside the `workflow.yml` file.

To make the project public I need another approach, where others cannot get the credentials.

How can I realize my idea?

Answer (score 1):

By coincidence, I have found a possible solution via [Github Secrets](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/github_actions_11_secrets.html).

Comment: GitHub Secrets is indeed the way of doing it, to keep everything in the same place. You could also use an external **deploy** system but that's more work.